# Scala String Interpolation in println - Accessing elements using dot notation

Tags: scala, syntax, println, string-interpolation

I have a `user` object with a few properties that I can access using dot notation.

For example, `user.fullName` outputs a String like `Firstname Lastname`.

How do I access these properties within a `println` statement that uses string interpolation?

I've tried the following:

```
println(s"user's full name is $user.fullName")
```

However, it doesn't seem to work with dot notation and only parses the entire `$user` object, interpreting the remaining `fullName` section as a string rather than a property. This incorrectly outputs:

> >> user's full name is User(...).fullName

The following is what I'm after:

> >> user's full name is Firstname Lastname

Help appreciated!

Comment: Just a suggestion ;): maybe you should rephrase the question because the way string interpolation works and accessing members with dot notation is not println specific.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved - looks like curly braces help interpret the entire variable, including properties that are accessed through dot notation.

The following code works:

```
println(s"user's full name is ${user.fullName}")
```

This outputs the following as expected:

> >> user's full name is Firstname Lastname